# Why does this Spring Boot MVC test fail when autowired dependency replaced with interface or abstract class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, groovy, spock

This is the Controller as it appears at the moment.

```
import com.myorg.service.MyService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/my/homepage")
    public String someMethod(ModelMap model, Authentication authentication) {
        myService.doSomething(authentication);
        return "homepage";
    }
}
```

Here is the Controller Advice to handle exceptions

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpStatusCodeException.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(HttpServletRequest req, HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    // do stuff
    return mav;
}
```

And this is the current test, which works fine

```
import com.myorg.service.MyService
import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
import spock.lang.Specification

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@SpringBootTest
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

    @SpringBean
    private MyService myService = Mock()


    @WithMockUser(username = "test@email.com",  roles = ["USER"])
    def "MyController(test=should not authenticate)"() {
        setup:
        def notAuthorizedException = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "blah", null, Charset.defaultCharset())
        MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build()
        myService.doSomething(_) >> { throw notAuthorizedException }

        when:
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(get("/my/homepage"))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andReturn()

        then:
        mvcResult.response.status == 302
        mvcResult.modelAndView.viewName == "redirect:/my/login?logout"
    }
}
```

The test passes successfully in that the mock throws the `HttpClientErrorException`, which the advice catches and then redirects the user to a logout page.

But when I replace the `MyService` member in the `MyController` class with a class that implements an interface, the test fails because the `HttpClientErrorException` is no longer being caught by the advice and instead is being thrown as a nested exception.

Here is the new Controller

```
import com.myorg.service.MyServiceThatImplementsAnInterface;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class MyController {

    private final MyInterface myInterface;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyInterface myInterface) {
        this.myInterface = myInterface;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/my/homepage")
    public String someMethod(ModelMap model, Authentication authentication) {
        myInterface.doSomething(authentication);
        return "homepage";
    }
}
```

Here is the interface implementation

```
@Component("myInterface")
public class MyServiceThatImplementsAnInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {


    private final SomeComponent someComponent;

    public MyServiceThatImplementsAnInterfaceImpl(SomeComponent comeComponent) {
        this.someComponent = someComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(Authentication authenticationToken) {
        someComponent.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

And here is the new test

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext

    @SpringBean
    private MyServiceThatImplementsAnInterfaceImpl myServiceThatImplementsAnInterface = Mock()


    @WithMockUser(username = "test@email.com",  roles = ["USER"])
    def "MyController(test=should not authenticate)"() {
        setup:
        def notAuthorizedException = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "blah", null, Charset.defaultCharset())
        MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build()
        myServiceThatImplementsAnInterface.doSomething(_) >> { throw notAuthorizedException }

        when:
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(get("/my/homepage"))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andReturn()

        then:
        mvcResult.response.status == 302
        mvcResult.modelAndView.viewName == "redirect:/my/login?logout"
    }
}
```

Here is the failing test stack trace

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at app//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:497)
    at app//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at app//org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at app//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
    at app//org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at app//org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at app//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at app//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at app//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at app//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at app//org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurer$DelegateFilter.doFilter(SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.java:132)
    at app//org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at app//org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
    at com.myorg.controller.MyControllerSpec.<where my test is>
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.myorg.controller.MyControllerSpec.<where my test is>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does your example compile? The `MyController` has a field of type `MyServiceThatImplementsAnInterface` but I only see `MyInterface` and `MyServiceThatImplementsAnInterfaceImpl` defined.

Comment: It might be a configuration problem. You posted many details, which is great. If you would not mind to walk the last mile and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, it would be easier for community members here to reproduce the problem and suggest a solution. 

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are also some classes missing which are required to run your code. Same goes for your Maven POM or Gradle config. E.g., where does the expected redirection come from?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my original post. Edited now. The code compiles, yes

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved and, as with about 90% of these kinds of problems, the error was simple to fix. In my test class, I simply hadn't assigned the exception handler class to the MockMvc.

```
def "MyController(test=should not authenticate)"() {
        setup:
        Authentication authentication = //Just mock out an Authentication object here
        def notAuthorizedException = //As before, just mock out an exception
        myInterface.doSomething(_) >> { throw notAuthorizedException }
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver()
        viewResolver.setPrefix("prefix")
        MyController myController = new MyController(myServiceThatImplementsAnInterface)
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(myController)
                .setControllerAdvice(new MyExceptionHandler())
                .setViewResolvers(viewResolver)
                .build()

        when:
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/my/homepage")
                .principal(authentication))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andReturn()

        then:
        mvcResult.response.status == 302
        mvcResult.modelAndView.viewName == "redirect:/app/login?logout"
    }
```

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = MyInterface.class)
public class MyExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(HttpStatusCodeException.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(HttpServletRequest req, HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        // do stuff
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, errors like these are usually easy to fix if the developer in question has access to a compilable, runnable project. That is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I requested from you. So next time, please please provide one, doing yourself and the community members who want to help you the biggest favour. From reading the code alone, next to nobody except you can debug it. But you asked others for help, so please make your problem reproducible to them, not just yourself.